# flexbox in react : doesn't resize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to display on screen a green block for 1/4 of the screen and a yellow block for 3/4 of the screen using react.js
I have the following code - but green block and yellow block has the same size.

MyComp.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './MyComp.css'

export default class MyComp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapp">
        <div className="greenBlock">
          <h1>green </h1>
        </div>
        <div className="yellowBlock">
          <h1>yellow </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

MyComp.css:

````
.wrapp,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapp {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.greenBlock {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0.25
}

.yellowBlock {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 0.75
}
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can use float values on the `flex` property.

here is a [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to use flex-box

You should do something like this:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display:flex;
}

.a{
  flex: 3;
  background-color: red;
}

.b{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}


.container-vertical{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>   
</div>
<br /> <br />
<div class="container-vertical">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Portella : your example helped me to find the problem but it is not float value. If I remove flex-direction: column; it works. Do you have any idea of why ?

Comment: When you change the flex-direction to column you change the axis of the flex container, so when you change the flex value of a child they will grow or shrink in the Y axis(height).

Comment: I've edit my answer to show you an example of how it works when your flex container have the flex-direction set to column

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the flex property `flex` and assign numbers in integer,
or you could also use the `flex-basis`  property, where you can also specify your desired ratio in %.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 200px;
}

.red{
  flex-basis: 66.66666%;
  background-color: red;

}

.green{
  flex-basis: 33.33333%;

  background-color: green;
}

/* OR */



.y{
 flex: 2;
 background-color: yellow;
}

.b{
 flex: 1;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="red"></div>
   <div class="green"></div>   
</div>
<br/>

<div class="container">
   <div class="y"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>   
</div>
```